# Multi language site how add specific category link in phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, category, custom, link

I have a multlanguage site, and I need to add a link of a category in phtml file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This won't be optimal and elegant solutions since you provided no information about layout structure so generally you can generate any link to a category on frontend like this:

```
$categoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getUrl();
```

It is very likely however that this url is already in the menu. I would create an observer for `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after` and fetch the category data from the Menu object passed to that event.

Comment: Hi, with this solution I show all category in another position. I need to make a link at one specific category can I adapt it to call the category by ID?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. In the solution I provided you need to get somehow id of a category as `load()` method accepts that by default. You do not show "all" category but only takes a link to it.